# Regarding Null Check Operator Used on a Null Value

Tags: flutter, nullreferenceexception

```
 BlocBuilder<SettingsBloc, SettingsState> _buildOpeningHours() {
    return BlocBuilder<SettingsBloc, SettingsState>(
            builder: (context, state) {
              if (state is SettingsLoading) {
                return const SizedBox();
              }
              if (state is SettingsLoaded){
                return ListView.builder(
                  itemBuilder: (context, index){
                    var openingHours= state.clinic.openingHours![index];
                    return OpeningHoursSettings(
                      openingHours: openingHours,
                      onCheckboxChanged: (value){
                        context.read<SettingsBloc>().add(UpdateOpeningHours(openingHours: openingHours.copyWith(isOpen: openingHours.isOpen)));
                      }, onSliderChanged: (value) {
                        context.read<SettingsBloc>().add(UpdateOpeningHours(openingHours: openingHours.copyWith(openAt:  value.start, closeAt: value.end)));
                      },
                    );
                  },
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  itemCount: state.clinic.openingHours!.length,
                );
              }else{
                return Text('Something went Wrong');
              }
            }
          );
```

I am pretty sure the problem is in
`itemCount: state.clinic.openingHours!.length`,
This part

[this is the error it shows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IG5iT.png)

If I change that line to
`state.clinic.openingHours?.length??0`
then it shows nothing like nothing

but if I change it to
`state.clinic.openingHours?.length??7`

It shows the same error

Comment: openingHours is null. check why it is null.

Answer (score 0):

If you put the version with  `?? 7` you get the error in a different line:
`var openingHours= state.clinic.openingHours![index];` because the itemBuilder is not called unless `itemCount` is unlike 0.
Since `state.clinic.openingHours` is null, adding  `?? 0` makes the `itemCount` be 0. You don’t get the error where you try to access an index in a null value then, because the `itemBuilder` function is not executed even once. As far as I can tell,  `?? 0` does makes the most sense.

I would recommend looking at the debug output in the Terminal/Console you are running the Flutter app from. Learning how to read a stack trace is very helpful.